# Adding Backbone.js to existing Spring MVC app

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, backbone.js, marionette

I'm working on a decently large Spring MVC app that continues to grow.  It's a traditional Spring MVC app with the views being JSP that renders the HTML which is returned to the browser.  The app uses a lot of javascript and jQuery plugins.  The javascript is scattered throughout the code and is getting harder to maintain.  We'd like to clean that up and move to a single page application.  We've looked into Backbone.js and specifically Marionette.  A couple questions we have:

1. How does Spring Security work with this?  As I understand, instead of JSPs and HTML returned from the server it will be JSON through a RESTful API.  So when the user logs in with a username/password do I need to generate an API key and send that down in a successful authentication response?  Then from that point forward every API call would have that API key part of it to authenticate each call?
2. Have others found success moving a traditional Spring MVC app with JSP views to a Javascript MVC view architecture with a RESTful API?  Is it worth it and any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some experience working on a similar project. If you need to perform frequent maintenance on the app the time you invest in cleaning up the client side code should pay off.  It can be easier than you think provided you reuse some of the existing server side code.

Chances are your existing mvc routes fit your domain well.  Rather than trying to implement a brand new api, you can adapt your existing
    spring controllers to return json.  Springs existing auth/session management will come along for free with this approach, saving you time and effort.

One thing to note.  You will need to handle 401 & 403 status codes returned from your backbone fetch methods.  Depending on your app it may be useful to setup a global handler for this.

**Global redirect for 401 /403**

```
App.on("initialize:after", function() {
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr) {
        if(xhr.status === 401) {
            window.location.href('/#sign-in');
        }else if(xhr.status === 403) {
            window.location.href('/#restricted');
        }
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
});
```